# Script URL with pound sign (hashtag) cut off when inserting in DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery

From an external resource I get URLs for trackers that I need to execute/load in the DOM, but a URL with a # in it, gets cut off after the pound sign, whatever I try. I have no control over these URLs as they come from a 3rd party, I want to be able to load this URL without any modification to it.
An example URL: http://www.example.com/resource.js?param1=testvalue#a=b&c=d&f=g&js=.js
When executed this URL changes into: http://www.example.com/resource.js?param1=testvalue

The code that I'm sharing works in all cases, except for the URL above.

Original code:

```
$('#myElement').append('<SCRIPT language="JavaScript1.1" SRC="' + url + '"></SCRIPT>')
```

What I tried too:

```
var s = document.createElement("script")
s.type = "text/javascript"
s.src = url
$('#myElement')[0].appendChild(s)
```

And other variations with appending the child, I tried to insert it as an image element too, but that didn't work either.

The only other post I could find on this suggests that the browser does this ([jQuery Ajax Call on URL with Pound (Number) Sign](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29753914/jquery-ajax-call-on-url-with-pound-number-sign) )...seems logical, but the company we're not the first client of this company...

Comment: So you want to pass "#" as parameter?

Comment: It comes down to that indeed, I just want to be able to execute that URL without doing any modifications to it.

Comment: Special characters in the query string need to be escaped. Fragment identifiers (anything after `#`) are not sent to the server by the browser. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery Ajax Call on URL with Pound (Number) Sign](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29753914/jquery-ajax-call-on-url-with-pound-number-sign)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what you need is to encode the url so you don't let the browser interpret the raw parameters. You can have a look on this post [Encode URL in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332872/encode-url-in-javascript) . And maybe check a little bit the documentation to understand why you need to do that.(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent). So you jsut have to redirect to encodeURIComponent(url) or when you add the parameters (link + encodeURIComponent(params)).

Comment: Thanks, this indeed would have fixed it. After some more back and forth the 3rd party was OK with replacing the # with a &, which before according to them wouldn't work.....I asked if we could stop working with clients and customers all together, but something about money... ;)