# Unexpected end of JSON input from AWS API Gateway

Tags: javascript, aws-api-gateway

I'm trying to setup an API Gateway REST API that prompts a Lambda function and returns some items from a DynamoDB table.

When I test the API in the AWS API Gateway console I am getting the correct data back, but getting a `Unexpected end of JSON input` error trying in JavaScript (just trying in JS Fiddle).

Here is my fetch function:

```
function fetchData(){
    fetch("https://abcd1234.execute-api.region.amazonaws.com/stage/product?productId=1234"
    ).then(response => {
        return response.json()
    }).then(jsonData => {
        console.log('success:', jsonData)
    }).catch(e => {
        console.log('error:', e.message)
        return e
    })
}
```

It's a get method in the Lambda function and I'm newer to this, so not sure what I'm doing wrong. If it was a CORS issue would I get a different message back?

Comment: Logging `response` won't be all that useful, resolve the promise returned by `response.text()` instead.

Comment: Thanks.  When I change `response.json()` to `response.text()` I get `""`. Does this indicate the API isn't returning the data I expect?

Comment: Yes. It seems to be returning nothing.

Comment: When I look at the URL in the response, it's not showing the complete API URL. Getting cut off at a `#` character. Is there any reason I'm not seeing the full URL in the response?

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45321834/script-url-with-pound-sign-hashtag-cut-off-when-inserting-in-dom

Comment: This was it all along. And should be the accepted answer.